# Submenu page buttons are blank

Tags: menus

https://mangonelsgames.com/
Is a website I built with elementor.

When extending the skills section on the main menu, sub-entries show blank, but you CAN click on them and are directed properly. Any idea why?

[image]

I tried reconfiguring the section from scratch, adding only 1 entry to the submenu... but it seems it's just staying blank.

Comment: That sounds like a CSS problem then. Can you use your browser's debug tools to see how the entries here are being styled? You can hopefully identify the CSS that's making them white-on-white and either reconfigure that in Elementor (? I don't know elementor) or supply extra CSS to style them better.

Comment: Not sure that elementor can allow me to edit CSS, the whole point of it is to abstract people from any actual code. I'll check this anyway though :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem in the generated CSS. This rule is adding a `color: #fff` to your menu links:

```
.ast-theme-transparent-header .main-header-menu .menu-link,
```

You can overwrite this rule in your CSS file and links will be visible. Check it out (the second CSS block):

[image]

There you go! :)

Answer (score 1):

This was a color issue I had to fix through the Astra theme's configuration. It was a bit hidden but I found it:

[image]

[image]

Sorry for not mentioning I was using Astra, but I'm basically kinda abstracted from css and html thanks to it, which aren't my specialties.

Comment: Hi Mithrandir! I'll be glad if you can select my answer as correct. Thanks!